# How to change the font style in \IEEEkeywords

Tags: fonts, ieeetran, italic

IEEE papers has `\IEEEkeyword` command to write the keywords. I used `\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Index Terms}` to change that text to Index Terms. But the font of the keywords I obtained is *italics* and not the normal font.

The expected form is this, 
***Index Terms*-words, letters**

But what I obtain is this, 
***Index Terms-words, letters***

How to obtain normal font instead of italics for all the index terms.

Comment: Your ending question states completely the opposite of the introduction. Would you please clarify?

Comment: In Werner's example, change `\itshape` to `\normalfont\bfseries`. is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert `\itshape` at the end of the `IEEEkeywords` environment-start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\let\oldIEEEkeywords\IEEEkeywords
\def\IEEEkeywords{\oldIEEEkeywords\itshape\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
words, letters
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi..What I need is words,letters in normal font, Not italics. Whereas "Index Terms" should be in italics.

Comment: @Vidhya: Can you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that the community can work with? When I create one without any adjustment, I obtain ***Index Terms*-words, letters** (your expected form).

Comment: I don know how to create minimal working example (MWE). Please tell me how.

Comment: @Vidhya: Did you *read* the [post](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? It should be a small document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. It should just contain enough information to recreate the problem. So, it should just be something that includes your `\IEEEkeywords`, say. Something that I can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're getting (even though it's wrong).

Comment: It worked..But now when index terms went correct the fig caption alignment changed. Fig caption should be left aligned as per IEEE format. But now I am getting it as centre aligned.

Comment: @Vidhya: *Please create a MWE that replicates the problem, starting with the first problem (the keywords)*. It's difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: @Vidhya: Werner's code is a right candidate to be called MWE.

Comment: \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Index Terms}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\title{Conference Paper}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Dept. \Organisation\Place\email}
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract is here
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
words,letters.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\section{Introduction}
Introduction...
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.35]{as}
\caption{circuit}
\label{ee}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Comment: @Vidhya: When I compile your MWE, I obtain [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XWhmt.png) where the keywords are displayed as ***Index Terms*-words, letters**, exactly as you mention in the expected form. In other words, you obtain exactly the question you pose at the end (without doing anything extra): "How to obtain normal font instead of italics for all the index terms?" So, my question still is, how can I replicate your problem via a MWE? If your output doesn't resemble mine, then add `\listfiles` to your preamble and include the contents after `*File List*` in your `.log` to your post.

Comment: Sometimes I obtain the correct expected form and sometimes I don,t. That is why I posted the question. When I get the index terms correct my fig caption changes to middle instead of left aligned. If fig caption alignment goes correct, then index terms will not be as expected. This is the actual problem I face.

Comment: @Vidhya: That's unfortunate, and just as difficult to analyse without any concrete document to work with. Output should be consistent, so *you* must be doing something different. Think of the problem from the perspective of the community. If we can help you, you need to help us and provide details in terms of *how we can replicate the problem*. Once we're able to replicate the problem, then we can work towards solving it. Until such time, it's really just crystal-ball guess-work to come up with a solution. Really.

Comment: ya I know.. I don know how to explain more than this :( :(

Comment: @Vidhya: Show a picture of what your output looks like. Exactly what you get when you compile the MWE. Do you get something that looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XWhmt.png)? If not, what then? Why haven't you followed my instructions in terms of `\listfiles`?

Comment: Ya I got exactly what u got..But the fig caption shud be left aligned instead of centre align.

Comment: @Vidhya: Under the `conference` style, captions are centered (*read* the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf), p 2). If this is for conference proceedings, then you should not change the style. Where did you read that it should be left-aligned? If you *want* it left-aligned, add `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{\hfil\box}{\box}{}{}
\makeatother` to your document preamble. You still haven't answered all my questions.

Comment: Thank you.. Now everything is perfect.. \usepackage{etoolbox} \makeatletter \patchcmd{\@makecaption}{\hfil\box}{\box}{}{} \makeatother worked perfect....In the sample conference papers fig is left aligned. I didn't try using \listfiles. I hope all questions are answered. Thank you so much